# Disable copying element styles together with it's innerText

Tags: html, css

When copying the element's text content and pasting it in the text editor like `Microsoft Word` or `OS X Pages` the styles of the element are also being included.

```css
p {
  background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<p>text</p>
```

From copying text highlighted like the image below:

[image]

Is there a proper CSS rule to enable copying only the text content? :)

Comment: this article has many useful related concepts but not the one you seek https://css-tricks.com/copy-paste-the-web/

Comment: "Is there a proper CSS rule to enable copying only the text content?" - No there isn't. You could *maybe* use some JavaScript to purge the styles.

Comment: Have you tried right click and "paste without formatting" in Word?